# Persisting mongoid parent document and embedded documents from Haml on Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, mongoid, haml

I have the following model:

```
class Entry
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :made, type: Date
  embeds_many :images
  embeds_many :videos
  embeds_many :files
  embeds_many :tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :videos, :files, :tags
  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :tags
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, :description
end

class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :tag, type: String
  embedded_in :entry
  embedded_in :note
end
```

The post route looks like this:

```
post '/portfolio/new' do
  a = (params[:entry])
  a['tags_attributes']['0']['tag'].downcase.split(", ").each_with_index{|value, index| a['tags_attributes'][index.to_s] = {"tag" => value} }
  b = Entry.new(a)
  b.safely.save!
  redirect "portfolio/show/#{b._id}"
end
```

and my haml input looks like:

```
%label{:for => "tags"} Tags:
%input{:name => "entry[tags_attributes[0[tag]]]"}
```

I'm new at Ruby/Sinatra/Mongoid, so I am still trying to figure out how to access documents attributes properly.

What I am trying to do is to process the http post information and be able to (almost immediately) save it to mongodb.

The haml method for placing the input values in the right place on the hash is one I found to work through trial and error. But it doesn't feel DRY, surely there is a better way write the embedded document? specifically entry[tags_attributes[0[tag]]] feels very akward, is there a better way of writing this?

Also in my route, in order to break the string of tags I have and store it back into the hash structure as individual embedded document before saving. I feel it's a very round-about-way of parsing this information.

What are the best practices for dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haml

```
%input{name: 'entry[tags_attributes][][tag]', value: t.tag}
```

Route simply

```
post '/portofolio/new' do
  Entry.new(params[:entry])
  ...
end
```

Be aware on edit/put don't forget the embedded id

```
%input{type: 'hidden', name: 'entry[tags_attributes][][id]', value: t.id}
```